# XML parser: invalid argument in iterating over array

Tags: php, arrays

I have looked at [examples](http://php.net/manual) of iterating over arrays, but get the following error when doing so myself:

> Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in
>   /home/cdlwebde/public_html/sofia_nikolsky911/Project/includes/load.php
>   on line 33.

This is the code I'm trying to execute:

```
// Convert the data string into two arrays.  The array $xml_contents will contain each 
// element in the XML file.  The array $tag_index will be an associative array organized
// by tag names with a list of the indexes where that tag occurs.
xml_parse_into_struct($parser, $data, $xml_contents, $index);

// Pull out the index array for just the object tag specified as a parameter to this
// function. This array will have the index for just the elements in the XML file with  
// the specified object tag.
$xml_object_index_array = $index[$xml_object_tag];  //$xml_object_tag is a string

// Loop through all the instances of that object tag, looking for each start tag. 
foreach ($xml_object_index_array as $occurrence=>$tag_index) 
{
    // do whatever
}
```

Comment: as an alternative, use [`SimpleXML`](http://php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.construct.php) instead

Comment: `Invalid argument supplied for foreach` means that `$xml_object_index_array` is actually not an array. This probably means that the `$xml_object_tag` string did not match anything in `$index`. Depending on your error reporting level, you might not see an undefined index notice.

Comment: `var_dump($xml_object_index_array)` should elaborate on @Don'tPanic's point

Comment: As stated by @Don'tPanic , before supplies to foreach, check if $xml_object_index_array is valid array.